# Missing Python DLL

Tags: python, c++, dll, embed

I'm trying to embed Python into C++, but when I compile and run the application, it just automatically closed. I ended up debugging it with [LLDB](https://lldb.llvm.org/). The result was the debugger saying that `The code execution cannot proceed because python36.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.` I have the latest version of python installed, currently version [3.9.5](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-395/). What does this error mean? I checked my python folder, and I have `python39.dll, python39_d.dll, python3.dll, and python3_d.dll` but not `python36.dll.` Is there a fix to this error? and if not, can someone refer to the version of python I can get this .dll from? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Five bucks says python 3.6

Comment: `python3.6.dll` means `Python 3.6`